# Using logic (smaller than, equal to, bigger than) in XAML datatrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, logic, datatrigger

I'm not that good with XAML but I want to have a data-trigger which is bound to a variable on my page.cs which is a double.

If the double is bigger than 0.25, I want it to trigger.
If it's 0.5 I want another one to trigger.

How would you do this kind of stuff?
Any pages to read up on this would be awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use converters implementing [`IValueConverter` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) which convert `double` to `bool`, based on a value of converter parameter.

For example a converter `DoubleMoreThanConverter` would accept `double` value, `double` converter parameter and return `bool` in `Convert` method. You can set `Converter` and `ConverterParameter` properties of a binding you put into `DataTrigger`.